# Upload Image File In Php Server Using multipart and httpUrlConnection and also want to send Some String Types Data

Tags: php, android

I Want to Send Image In Server And Also Want to send String information in Server Using  multipart url and httpUrlConnection in Post Method not using httpclient bcz httpclient is deprecated .

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring that out.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/32474021/5309236

I have shared a method for multipart files upload along with strings.